# JavaScript | Proper way to format code

Tags: javascript, oop

I am new to JavaScript and have a question to ask. When creating a new programme is it best to create all of my functions within a global variable/object or to create them all separate.

For example this:

```
var register = {
    members: [],    
    Member: function(){ 
    },
    reset: function(){  
    },
    printMembers: function(){   
    },
    process: function(){    
    }
};

function init(){
    register.process();
};

window.onload = init();
```

Or instead like this:

```
var members = [];

function Member(){
};
function reset(){
};
function printMembers(){
};
function process(){
};

function init(){
    process();
};

window.onload = init();
```

This may be a very stupid question to ask...

Comment: It totally depends, but if functions are tightly related IMO they should be grouped to reflect this. It also avoids polluting the global namespace, which is important.

Comment: just for start: take a look to http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: JBTW: JavaScript is normally indented with 4 spaces

Comment: So both are correct but it comes down to context and situation? If the functions/methods are for the running of the programme they should be stored together? Same as if they are the methods for a certain object they should be stored together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When creating a new programme is it best to create all of my functions within a global variable/object or to create them all separate.

This is kind of opinion based, but I'll give you a good reason for creating all your properties inside a global object: you won't pollute the namespace. That means, you won't be creating a lot of global objects, that would be properties of the global object (`window`, in browsers).

If you use someone else's library, and if both you and him would create global objects, the script that was included later in the HTML would override properties with the same name declared in the other script.

Finishing, I would suggest you to write your code like:

```
var app = {};

app.members = [];

app.Member = function(){};

app.reset = function(){};

app.printMembers = function(){};

app.process = function(){};

function init() {
    app.process();
};

window.onload = init;
```

Also, note that you should do `window.onload = init`, and not `window.onload = init()`.

The difference:

- with `window.onload = init`, you are setting the `onload` property in `window` to be the `init` function. Later, when the page finishes loading, someone will ask the `window` to execute its `onload` property, and `window` will then do something like `this.onload()`.
- with `window.onload = init()`, you are executing `init` right there and setting the `onload` property of `window` to be the return of the execution of the `init` function. Since every Javascript function returns something (by default, `undefined`), you'll be setting `window.onload = undefined`. And this is not what you want.

Comment: This is a very clean answer that answers the question I had exactly, even though my question was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of taste style--kindof like writing an essay.  Ultimately, what's important is that anyone (or you, six months from now) can read through your code and understand what's going on.  Just focus on functionality and you will naturally start making decisions about what's logical where.

(Eloquent Javascript)[http://eloquentjavascript.net//] is also a great book on the subject.